# Installing Nvidia driver Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, drivers, nvidia

I downloaded this driver from the Nvidia website: NVIDIA-Linux-x86-310.44.run

How do I install this file?

Comment: You blacklist the nouveau driver, switch to a different tty, stop xserver, cd to the right directory, and then run `sudo sh NVIDIA-Linux-x86-310.44.run`. If that sounds too complicated, just search for Additional Drivers in the Dash.

Comment: @mikewhatever When I search for Additional Drivers in the Dash it says that I already have the recommended driver as current driver, but when I installed Stream, it gave me the notification that I should update?

Comment: @ygoygo12345 Yes, the driver for Steam is not the recommended one. It's labeled as experimental in the Additional Drivers, and you can easily install it after removing the recommended one. You can't have two drivers active for the same peice of hardware at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

cd to the directory where the downloaded file is then:

```
sudo sh NVIDIA-Linux-x86-310.44.run
```

You may want to read up on the full process here:

http://us.download.nvidia.com/XFree86/Linux-x86/310.44/README/installdriver.html#BeforeYouBegin89f39

Answer (score 0):

I installed it through synaptics.

nvidia-experimental-310-dev
nvidia-settings-experimental-310